# Can I evade a where clause with a parameter instead of adding OR 1=1 to the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Now I have a long query and I'd like to alternate with such a statement

```
where userid=@userid
```

But I have other parameters which change flow, so, I want to have two options, selecting one user or any user

Can I send a username so that It can select and user? like we do in LIKE statements, we send

```
where username LIKE "%%"
```

and we get all records, how can I do that with INT?

Because my query is parameterized, I can't add "OR 1=1" like

```
where userid=1 or 1=1
```

should I use BETWEEN and get two parameters, so when I select one record, I'll enter userid-1 and userid+1 as two paramters, and get one user, and when I wand to select all, I'll enter 1 and 1 million.

Is it a logical way for parameterized queries or is there another way, with one parameter?

SOLUTION
[image: This is how I use the solution, when you use the or column on the right, your sql will be broken.]

Comment: So are you saying you want to use the same query to get all users or one user, and you want to specify which behavior based on the parameters you pass in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically this is done using

```
WHERE userid = @userid OR @userid IS NULL
```

Another variation (if the userid column is not nullable):

```
WHERE userid = COALESCE(@userid, userid)
```

Yet another (for ints) is to say

```
WHERE userid BETWEEN COALESCE(@userid, 1)
    AND COALESCE(@userid, 2000000000); -- well, 2147whatever
```

But if you have a lot of these conditions and every time the query is run the parameters change, you could be locking yourself into bad plans that aren't always appropriate. So sometimes the answer is to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @userid IS NOT NULL THEN 
    N' AND userid = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @userid);
```

Couple this with `OPTION RECOMPILE` and/or the instance setting "optimize for ad hoc workloads" you'll only stuff up the plan cache with plans for versions of the query that are executed more than once.

Comment: the first statement is what I've been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: for the future viewers, query builder of mssql ruins the sql code when you try that format.

Comment: There's an easy fix for that: stop using the query builder. It's absolutely full of bugs and undesirable behavior.

Comment: I fixed the query buildr problem, now I have a screenshot of it in the question body.

Answer (score 2):

Would something along the following lines work?

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID OR @SelectAllUsers = 1
```

You set up @SelectAllUsers as an integer you can pass as 1 or any other number. If it's 1, it will select all users, otherwise you'll only select the passed in user.

Answer (score 1):

```
where userId > -1
```

would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized queries are there to keep sql injection from happening. Why don't you make a specific query with no parameters or WHERE clause like `SELECT * FROM users`?